# Querying multiple indexes in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have a main+delta index in Sphinx. When I query the main index, using this query, I get 4 rows back:

```
mysql> SELECT id, category_id FROM `product_core` WHERE MATCH('@category_id 122') ;
+-------+-------------+
| id    | category_id |
+-------+-------------+
|  3384 | 122 120     |
| 24405 | 122 120     |
| 24483 | 122 120     |
| 24519 | 122 120     |
+-------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

When I query the delta index, I get 1 row back:

```
mysql> SELECT id, category_id FROM `product_delta` WHERE MATCH('@category_id 122') ;
+------+-------------+
| id   | category_id |
+------+-------------+
| 3384 | 122 120     |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

According to the examples I've found around, this combined query should then give me 4 rows, with the delta row replacing the main row:

```
mysql> SELECT id, category_id FROM `product_core`, `product_delta` WHERE MATCH('@category_id 122') ;
+------+-------------+
| id   | category_id |
+------+-------------+
| 3384 | 122 120     |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

But this doesn't happen. Instead I get just the same result as if querying delta alone (1 row).

What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Not sure what the cause is - but I'd recommend using an attribute for category_id instead of a field, given you're matching integers. Curious as to whether things would work more reliably then?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this one out. I had a `sql_query_killlist` in my index that used to be correct. But I had changed the way that document_id's were generated and not updated the killlist correspondingly. The result naturally being rather random.